# How to properly get a constructor to work?

Tags: javascript, constructor

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I just can not seem to figure this out even though I feel like the code I am trying is correct. It is giving me an error that `sayName` and `takeAttendance` are not functions. Thanks in advance!

Here is what I am trying:

```
function Cohort(program, campus, number, students=['Bill', 'Ted', 'Bob']) {
  this.program = program;
  this.campus = campus;
  this.number = number;
  this.students = students;
  this.sayName = function() {
    return 'This cohort is called ' + this.program + this.campus + this.number;
  }
  this.takeAttendance = function() {
    console.log(this.students);
  }
}

cohort1 = {
  program: 'w',
  campus: 'pr',
  number: 27,
  students: ['Preston', 'Katie', 'Chester']
}

cohort2 = {
  program: 'w',
  campus: 'pr',
  number: 31,
  students: ['Brendan Eich', 'Dan Abramov', 'Wes Bos', 'Kent Dodds', 'Billy Bob']
}

cohort1.sayName();
cohort2.takeAttendance();
```

Comment: Please add what is or is not working.  Don't dump the assignment requirements and expect an implementation.

Comment: You are actually never invoking the constructor, just creating plain objects - try `var cohort1 = new Cohort('w', 'pr', 27, ['Preston', 'Katie', 'Chester'])`

Comment: @zero298 I made the edit. It is giving me and error that `sayName` and `takeAttendance` are not functions.

Comment: You do not even call Cohort..... so how do you think it would be connected to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually creating `Cohort`s.  Consider how you are making `cohort1`:

```
cohort1 = {
  program: 'w',
  campus: 'pr',
  number: 27,
  students: ['Preston', 'Katie', 'Chester']
}
```

There is nothing here that tells the JavaScript engine to create a `Cohort`.  Instead, you are assigning an Object literal to the variable `cohort1`.

Instead, you need to actually **call** the `Cohort` function that you created:

```
var cohort1 = new Cohort("w", "pr", 27, ['Preston', 'Katie', 'Chester']);
```

You can see this working correctly in the runnable snippet below.

```js
function Cohort(program, campus, number, students = ['Bill', 'Ted', 'Bob']) {
  this.program = program;
  this.campus = campus;
  this.number = number;
  this.students = students;
  this.sayName = function() {
    return 'This cohort is called ' + this.program + this.campus + this.number;
  }
  this.takeAttendance = function() {
    console.log(this.students);
  }
}

// Use new Cohort(...) to actually create a Cohort and assign it to cohort1
var cohort1 = new Cohort("w", "pr", 27, ['Preston', 'Katie', 'Chester']);

console.log(cohort1.sayName());
```